# ASP.NET OWIN Middleware - modify HTTP response

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I need to **intercept** all the **aspx** and **js** file requests and to **replace some text labels** if they are present. This middleware should work as an IIS module, obviously without interfering with the normal flow of the web application. 
I wrote some code but I have no idea how to do it.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(typeof(FilterMiddleware), Console.Out);
    }
}

public class FilterMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private readonly TextWriter logger;
    private readonly OwinMiddleware nextMiddleware;

    public FilterMiddleware(OwinMiddleware nextMiddleware, TextWriter logger) : base(nextMiddleware)
    {
        this.nextMiddleware = nextMiddleware;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var headers = context.Request.Headers;

        // IF .js OR .ASPX REPLACE TEXT HERE //

        await nextMiddleware.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is

```
if (context.Request.ContentType = "application/json") // or whatever MIME type
{
   ...
}
```

Then once you do all your processing, don't forget to create a response back

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
string result = ""; // whatever string you are sending back
await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
```

However, if it snags some kind of error, such as an unsupported method (ie PUT)

```
context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed;
await context.Response.WriteAsync(String.Empty);
```

Comment: and how to access to the original response body to replace text?

Comment: @Rick -- that is not a straightforward answer, so I refer you to this article that does a great job of giving you several solutions https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/aspnet-core-request-body/